# getAttribute() Error

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error in firefox about getAttribute not being a function. Below is my code with the error line marked.

```
    var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(item in nodeList){
        try{
        if(nodeList[item].getAttribute("type") == "file"){
            //ERROR HERE///->var id = nodeList[item].getAttribute("id");
            var fileSelector = document.getElementById(id);
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("change",function(e){
                if(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                if (fileSelector.files) {
                    window.file = fileSelector.files[0];
                } else {
                    window.file = fileSelector.value;
                }
                readData();
            });
        }
        }catch(e){}
    }
```

Comment: Don't iterate over arrays or array like objects with `for...in`. Use a normal `for` loop instead. The value of the property `nodeList.length`, which you are iterating over as well, is a number not a DOM element, hence the error.

Comment: Have you tried echoing what "item" is equal to when you receive the error. As Felix said, you shouldn't use `for...in` with an array. It's for iterating an object. Use `for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i)` instead.

Comment: Some JS libs modify how arrays are initialised and add extra elements to them. Try `if(!(nodeList[i] instanceof HTMLElement)) continue;`

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Actually [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) is not an Array, it's an object having two properties (`item()` and `length`) in additional to the HTMLElements.

Comment: @Teemu still, checking for the current item being instance of HTMLElement avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
 var nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 var max = nodeList.length;
    for(var i=0; i<max ; i++){
        try{
        if(nodeList[i].getAttribute("type") == "file"){
            //ERROR HERE///->var id = nodeList[item].getAttribute("id");
            var fileSelector = document.getElementById(id);
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("change",function(e){
                if(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                if (fileSelector.files) {
                    window.file = fileSelector.files[0];
                } else {
                    window.file = fileSelector.value;
                }
                readData();
            });
        }
        }catch(e){}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `nodeList[item]` is not a Node. Use a `for` loop instead of `for..in`:

```
var i, len = nodeList.length;
for(i=0; i<len; i += 1){
    try {
        if(nodeList[i].getAttribute("type") == "file"){
            // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuhYX/) for an explanation

```
for (item in nodeList)
```

gives `0`, `1` and `2` as the array indices, which is ok.

But then it delivers more properties `length`, `item` and `namedItem`, which aren't DOM elements and don't have a `getAttribute()` function.

So, as others have already suggested, use a normal for loop.